# How to get text from pdf preserving original formatting (with CTX_DOC)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, pdf-parsing, bfile

I use this code to filter text from `pdf` file:

```
create or replace directory pdf_dir as '&1';

create or replace directory l_curr_dir as '&3';

declare
  ll_clob     CLOB;
  l_bfile     BFILE;
  l_filename  VARCHAR2(200) := '&2';
begin
  begin
    ctx_ddl.drop_preference('testfilter');
    ctx_ddl.drop_policy('testdimac_policy1');
  exception when others then
    null;
  end;

  ctx_ddl.create_preference('testfilter', 'AUTO_FILTER');
  ctx_ddl.create_policy('testd_policy1', 'testfilter');

  l_bfile := bfilename('PDF_DIR', l_filename);

  dbms_lob.fileopen(l_bfile);

  ctx_doc.policy_filter(
      policy_name => 'test_policy1'
    , document    => l_bfile
    , restab      => ll_clob
    , plaintext   => true
    , CHARSET     => 'US7ASCII'
  );

DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (ll_clob,'L_CURR_DIR' , '&4');
/
```

The solution is good and working for me, but is there any way to get the tabular data, right now it is filtering text phrase by phrase or line by line.

For exeample, if pdf contains values like:

```
Name:            Amount  
Pradeep          100 USD
```

I want the output as is, but the current setup gives the output like:

```
Name:
Amount
Pradeep
100 USD
```

Is there any way to get the original format of text in `pdf`?

Is it possible to change the filter?

Comment: By "output as it is" I presume you mean how it appears when viewed through a PDF reader. Oracle does not to my knowledge have a built in PDF viewer; the data is stored as data, and the query you are running is returning .... the data.

Comment: thanks for your comment. even i think Oracle cannot support the formatted text as of now.